# How can I address my website product content being considered duplicate because it's on retailer websites?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, ecommerce, content

Currently I provide retailers (e.g. Amazon) with the same product content that's on my website. However, I want to do my best to get my website ranking over retailers, especially for brand terms.

Does anyone know the best way to go about this? Should I provide retailers with slightly different content, or is there another solution that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is rankings, you definitely need to create unique content on your website - not just slightly different, but completely different. Larger retailers will tend to outrank you simply because they have enough brand value that their SEO is inherently better, even when their content is not as good. Smaller businesses can outrank by optimizing for longer-tail keywords and by adding unique content and value to their sites. Be sure that if you go to this trouble of creating unique content, you also periodically check the retailers' websites and make sure they are not copying the descriptions from your site.

In addition to the products themselves, I've had good success with creating related value-added content. For example, I used to sell scooter accessories, and I personally found it hard to locate dealerships. So I did a lot of Googling and made a scooter dealership directory, complete with filters for what brands each one sold. I got a ton of relevant traffic from that - people who were interested in buying or servicing their scooters - and that did more for my SEO than all the product copy optimization I could have done.

Answer (score 0):

At first, Please read the Google Duplicate Content Guideline. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en&vid=0-165236925537-1524711212274

As your goal is to get rank in SERPs, you have to create unique content for your website. For Affiliate site in every category page at the ending/footer option, you can add unique content for getting the value of SEO. So that easily you can get rank.

For most of the product content, you cannot change content because of having some condition like product specification, user manual, brand etc. But you can write about the product usefulness from your part including some targeted keywords.

Also, You can add some infographics, videos, slide etc.